# No matching unique or primary key for this column-list: SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with SQL and I am running into error ORA-02270.

```
SQL> drop table employee;

Table dropped. 

SQL> Create Table Employee(
     age          varchar(2),
     gender          char(1),
     employee_no     char(6),
         references worksite(employee_no),
     Primary Key(age, gender)
     );

Table created.


SQL> Create Table Employee_type(
     age             varchar(2)
         references Employee(age),
     gender          char(1)
         references Employee(gender),
     employee_type   Varchar(12),

     Primary Key (age, gender, employee_type)
);


ERROR at line 3:

ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list.
```

I have read other posts but I still dont understand this error? I thought it might be because I have a composite key but I reference all columns of the composite key.

Comment: @Farhęg, thanks, can you give me an example of what I would need to do to define a unique constraint? Im new to SQL and I am not exactly sure I understand completely! thank you for your quick reply!

Comment: uhm, is this for mysql, sql-server AND oracle?

Comment: no sorry, just sql, i must have accidentally clicked the suggested, ill fix

Comment: What are you trying to do? `Age,gender` is not a useful or realistic primary key.

Comment: Im just trying to figure out what causes this error, this example is just using random variable names. I am more concerned on the logic behind the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Means exactly what it says... in some obscure way :-)

In [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) MySQL doc says:

> You are advised to use foreign keys that reference only keys that are
>   both UNIQUE (or PRIMARY) and NOT NULL.

In other words when you write `age varchar(2) references Employee(age)` it is necessary that Employee(age) has been defined as a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY.

Will be the same for Employee(gender).

Comment: I thought thats what I am doing, declaring it a primary key, or is it because it is a composite key so age is not actually a primary key but instead the combination of age and gender are a composite key?

Comment: How would i define age/gender as unique? im new to sql syntax?

Comment: CONSTRAINT uc_gender UNIQUE (age, gender)

Comment: Yes: the referenced column must be a non-composite key, in order MySQL to be able to look directly through this index to retrieve the value of your referencing column (alone) .

Comment: so will that line of code work? I dont have access to the db at this time

Comment: Oops... Had not seen your previous comment --> you may add `UNIQUE KEY(age)` and `UNIQUE KEY(gender)` to your `CREATE TABLE Employee` definition. In the other hand you may also use the alternative way proposed by MatBailie.

Answer (score 0):

I think you *intended* to use a "composite" foreign key constraint, which has the following syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_type(
  age             varchar(2),
  gender          char(1),
  employee_type   Varchar(12),
  PRIMARY KEY (age, gender, employee_type),
  CONSTRAINT fk_employee FOREIGN KEY(age,gender) REFERENCES Employee(age,gender)
);
```

This allows you to take more than one field from your table and link them both (together) with the matching fields in another table.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CONSTRAINT to set for composite foreign keys.
I hope it works for you.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_type(
  age             varchar(2),
  gender          char(1),
  employee_type   Varchar(12),
  PRIMARY KEY (age, gender, employee_type),
  CONSTRAINT fk_employee_age_gender FOREIGN KEY(age,gender) 
  REFERENCES Employee(age,gender)
```

);